# Python: Create a directory with data and time

Tags: python, subprocess

By using subprocess module , how can we create a directory with today's date and time as directory name ?
I can follow one process , like assigning todays date to a variable in the the python and use that variable as reference to create a directory.

And I am using windows as my target machine.

but is there any other best ways I could follow ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use subprocess, rather than [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because creating date folder is not the end of my script. Thank you

Comment: What? How does that have anything to do with anything?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I read that we can use subprocess more efficiently than os module. You like to "os" , and I'd like to use "subprocess" , thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that you can rely upon your system's timezone setting, you may use built in `date` command (on Unix-like systems) in a way like this:

```
os.system("mkdir `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`")
```

Though, there are other solutions, like to use `os.mkdir()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out.

The following will create a folder with the current date as its name. See the 'man date' to adjust the output to your liking.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('mkdir "$(date)"', shell=True)
```